# SQL QUERY Select employee who under a specific boss

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

A challenging question, i have table like below

EmployeeID    BossID

[pic http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/7659/20130430113245.jpg](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/7659/20130430113245.jpg)

any idea to create the query so that when certain employee go in , it will query all employee under him and who is his boss

Comment: Based on your image, did you mean to say "query all employee under the logged in employee including the logged-in-user's boss"? If yes then please update your question to that so others can answer properly.

Comment: YES.... you are correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query

You have to use CTE as Sohail has mentioned.

```
WITH DirectReports (bossId, EmpID, Level)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT bossId, empId,
        0 AS Level
    FROM tbl
    WHERE empId = 2
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT e.bossId, e.empId,
        Level + 1 AS Level
    FROM tbl e
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d
        ON e.bossId = d.empId
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT *
FROM DirectReports;
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0803b/4)**

```
| BOSSID | EMPID | LEVEL |
--------------------------
|      1 |     2 |     0 |
|      2 |     4 |     1 |
|      4 |     5 |     2 |
|      4 |     6 |     2 |
```

Comment: Thanks, @Meherzad , Great answer. this is what i want. is that possible to get the data of his boss which is Employee ID=1 and BossID=NULL into the query. because we need this info too. Appreciate if you able to help it out

Answer (score 3):

You should create the query using the CTE(Common table expression). For help you can read [Recursive Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Below is just similar example you can modify as per your need but it would help.

This is a table structure.

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categories](
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CategoryName] varchar NULL,
[ParentId] [bigint] NULL)

This is the hierarchical query. I just created a view for it because I need to filter it more in my scenario.

```
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CategoriesWithNameHierarchy] AS WITH Categories_Tree AS
        (SELECT c.id AS 'Id' ,
            0 AS 'Level',
            c.CategoryName AS 'CategoryName',
            cast(c.CategoryName AS varchar(30)) AS 'CNameHierarchy'
           FROM Categories c
   WHERE ParentId IS NULL
   UNION ALL SELECT ChildCategories.Id AS 'Id',
                    (1 + ct.[Level]) AS 'Level',
                    ChildCategories.CategoryName AS 'CategoryName',
                    cast(ct.CNameHierarchy + '>' + ChildCategories.CategoryName AS varchar(30)) AS 'CNameHierarchy'
   FROM Categories ChildCategories,
                   Categories_Tree ct
   WHERE ChildCategories.ParentId = ct.Id)
SELECT *
FROM Categories_Tree
```

Hope this would help.